# Wrap text in a dropdown

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

I am maintaining an application which can receive a particular PDF loaded with PDF digital drop downs and extract the selections from it. It will then input this into the database. The system works fine, but we also have a small console application that generates the particular PDF file, which we use in case the PDF needs to change.

An issue has been flagged up with the dropdown boxes. The dropdowns will usually host very long answers to questions and ideally, these should be wrapped so they are easily readable. Instead, the current generated PDF does not wrap but instead shows the selection on one line, which results in the text size fluctuating between dropdowns, with some being insanely small and difficult to read.

My question is - is there a way in iTextSharp to wrap the text shown within the drop downs? I tried googling it but I did not receive any answers relating to iText in general but for Acrobat.

Now this is where I think this question becomes futile. We want to wrap the text without using line breaks, so that the input method on the other side doesn't misconstrue the answers.

We are using iTextSharp 5.5.0 to generate the PDF, and the EasyPDF proprietary package to read off from the PDF. I can't provide screenshots of the PDF for confidentiality reasons, but please let me know if my description is not helpful and I will generate an example of what I am talking about.

The below code is a snippet from a switch that controls the drop down creation.

```
AddTextCell(table, question.Qno);
AddTextCell(table, question.Text, 1, 2);
cell = new PdfPCell 
{ 
   CellEvent = new ChoiceFields(
       question.Id.ToString(),
       question.PossibleAnswers.Select(x => x.Text).ToList(), 
       question.PossibleAnswers.Select(x => x.Id.ToString()).ToList(), 
       0) 
};
cell.MinimumHeight = 15f;
cell.Colspan = 3;
cell.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
cell.NoWrap = false;
table.AddCell(cell);
```

Comment: Providing a code sample of how you generate the dropdown boxes might be useful. Also, specifying the exact iTextSharp version number might help, in case a later version fixed a bug in that particular area.

Comment: Thanks Alexis, I have made the changes you recommended.

Comment: I'm beginning to think this feature is not supported by the PDF document format. I received an older company PDF which supposedly had multiple-lined drop downs, but when I opened it every option was one line with a tooltip showing the rest.